# How to add image icon on the left of Github Repository' description

Tags: git, github

I want to add this  icon to my project, but it says:

```
Error saving your changes: Description contains unicode characters above 0xffff
```

[image]

[image]

I want to make my repository's description like this:

[image]

Means it has an image on the left of description.

How to do this?

[image]

Comment: @halfer I have just restored it.

Comment: Great, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, there are github emojis which you can use with `:+1:` for example and these work even in description.

If you find your icon(or similar one) in these, you have it solved. You can try them in comments and it'll display you every emoji you can use in alphabetical order.

Or [here](https://gist.github.com/AliMD/3344523), which is a gist. Display "raw" and you'll see the text in `: ... :`.

Answer (score 6):

I change my description like this:

```
:cyclone: A self-taught project to learn Swift.
```

and it work now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The code point of the emoji you want to place in the description is [U+1F300](http://unicode-table.com/en/1F300/) (note that this is a hexadecimal number). Because 1F300 > FFFF, GitHub won't allow you to use that emoji.

Wait, you can use `:cyclone:`!

Comment: Btw [here](http://www.emoji-cheat-sheet.com/)'s a list of any and all emojis you can use that way.